# Connection to RDS works fine, but can't run MySQL commands

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-ec2, command-line

I'm trying to import a SQL file full of tables to MySQL.

I used the following command in Java to import the entire file, and it worked locally on my machine, but I ran into issues making this code work on Amazon's ec2:

```
try 
{
    restoreCmd = new String[]{"mysql ","--user="+doc.getDatabaseUserName(), "--password="+doc.getDatabasePass(),"--host="+doc.getDatabaseHostUri(),"-e","source " + file.getAbsolutePath()};

    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
        System.out.println("Inserted into RDS");
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Can someone give me an example of baked code that works to do a similar job with JDBC, reading the SQL file and importing it?

**EDIT**
I have updated the code to wait for the runtime process and check the exit value. It returns 1 which is a fail but the command still works locally. Strange, and I am unsure what causes the exit value to be 1 if it works locally to insert.

**Updated Code**

```
String[] restoreCmd;
        try 
        {

            restoreCmd = new String[]{"mysql ","--user="+doc.getDatabaseUserName(), "--password="+doc.getDatabasePass(),"--host="+doc.getDatabaseHostUri(),"-e","source " + file.getAbsolutePath()};

            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(restoreCmd);
                int processComplete = p.waitFor();
                if(processComplete == 0){

                    System.out.println("Backup taken successfully");
                    System.out.println("Inserted into RDS");

                } 
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Could not take mysql backup");
                }
                } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Can you print the command to the `STDOUT` and see if that works? Is the DB username, password and host uri OK for ec2?

Comment: Yes, there is other parts of the app were I connect to RDS and read tables . But I have a .sql file that hold an entire schema with 10 tables that I just want to import the file to my database. This command line works locally but ec2 can't run it . So I am looking for a work around to do the same job maybe reading the sql file and importing it using jdbc instead.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring process output to stdout and stderr, which may lead to the process blocking as soon as the buffer is full, see ["When Runtim.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) (especially "Why Runtime.exec() hangs")

Comment: Thank you , let me read that and get back to you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have updated the code to above. Is that what you meant by ignoring process output to stdout and stderr?

Comment: Why cant you SSH to an EC2 instance and use the command-line mysql client (what you're exec'ing here) to load the DB?